# How to populate model with having model django?

Tags: sql, django, database, model

I have model `People`:

with `name, phone email, address` fields

using Django's management commands I want populate `Contact` model
with the same fields

command file:
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Sorting leads '

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

1.Multiple People with the same name and phone number should be merged together, so the resulting Contact contains
all emails and addresses from merged Leads.
2. Multiple People with the same name, but different phone number and e-mail should be saved as separate contacts

How have I do it ? Should I do with raw sql or there is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to go to raw sql. From your description you can do this fairly easily within the ORM

```
#Add this import to top
from django.db.models import Value, BooleanField

...

#get everyone, and mark them as unprocessed
qs = People.objects.all().annotate(processed=Value(False, output_field=BooleanField()))

for person in qs:
    #is there someone with the same name and phonenumber?
    person_num = qs.filter(name=person.name, phone=person.phone, processed=False).count()
    #No, they are unique, so make a contact
    if person_num == 1:
        Contact.objects.create(name = person.name, 
            phone = person.phone,
            email = person.email,
            address = person.address)
    #Yes, there is more than one, set up some lists to capture data
    elif person_num > 1:
       phone_list = []
       email_list = []
       address_list = []
       #loop through qs for people with same name and phone number and gather their details
       for p in qs:
           if (p.name == person.name) and (p.phone==person.phone) and (p.id not person.id) and not p.processed:
               #check list before adding to avoid duplicate phones etc
               if p.phone not in phone_list:
                   phone_list.append(p.phone)
               if p.email not in email_list:
                   phone_list.append(p.email)
               if p.address not in address_list:
                   phone_list.append(p.address)
               p.processed = True

       Contact.objects.create(name = person.name,
           #stringify our lists with a ; seperator
           phone = ';'.join(str(x) for x in phone_list,
           email = ';'.join(str(x) for x in email_list,
           address = ';'.join(str(x) for x in address_list,)
   #check off this person as processed
   person.processed=True
```

Comment: thank you for your answer . I got error TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): False.

Comment: Hopefully have fixed that with Value()

Comment: could explain more?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I updated the line beginning qs= to fix that error (which requires an additional import now at the top of the code)

Comment: thanks) it helps. but i got an error in line  lead_num = Lead.objects.filter(
                name=lead.name, phone=lead.phone, processed=False).count(), ----django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'processed' into field.

Comment: Updated again - I needed to re-use qs rather than start another People.objects query.

Comment: thanks, it starts adding into db info , but I'he noticed that its not combine emails, addresses into 1 column if name and phone matches .

Comment: Ive noticed that i have no one lead with  count> 1, every count == 1

Comment: I tidied my code a little, but it shouldn't affect that. That would seem to be a data issue. If there's only ever 1 person with the same name and phone, then that's what the data has

Comment: I get the same count of contacts as leads , thats not correct

Comment: You may need to output the list of people and verify there is someone with the same name and phone number as someone else. You'll need to make sure their names aren't written differently, or that phone numbers don't have spaces in different places, or anything like that, because that would also fail to match.